# Jquery multiple checkboxes with same id issue

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have this problem with multiple checkboxes with the samen id (#group) if one of these checkboxes is checked another checkbox with the id (#user) should be checked as well. The problem is that with $this it works like a charm but then again you have also the checkboxes without the #group id. I made this fiddle to demonstrate the problem.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/njcw9Lav/1/
```

here is the simple Jquery

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
  var totalSeen = $("input#group:checked").length;
  if ($('#group').prop("checked")) {
    $('#user').prop('checked', true);
    return;
  } else if (totalSeen == 0) {
    $('#user').prop('checked', false);
    return;
  }
});
```

Comment: this only works with the first checkbox with the id #group the other checkboxes with the id #group are not working..

Comment: you don't have to use the same ID

Comment: It's a bad practice, to use multiple `id`s with the same values...

Comment: Thats what classes are for.

Comment: You can't re-use `id` values in the DOM.  They are meant to *identify* the element.  As long as your HTML is invalid, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Browser behavior for handling multiple instances of the same ID is officially undefined. In other words, there is no reliable way to know how a browser will react to that, although most will simply select the first occurrence. IDs are used internally by the browser to create a hash map/index of all DOM nodes, that's why they have to be unique. Solution? **Don't recycle IDs**. Use classes.

Comment: I dont get it... I have seen much better asked questions on SO downvoted to hell but this one doesnt get a single one.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can't give the same `id` to multiple [**HTML ELEMENTS**](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp) you should use `class` instead, so this:

```
    <input type="checkbox" class="edit-checkbox" name="groups[]" value="4" id="group">
    <input type="checkbox" class="edit-checkbox1" name="groups[]" value="4" id="group">
    <input type="checkbox" class="edit-checkbox" name="groups[]" value="4" id="group">
```

should be written like this:

```
    <input type="checkbox" class="edit-checkbox group" name="groups[]" value="4" >
    <input type="checkbox" class="edit-checkbox1 group" name="groups[]" value="4" >
    <input type="checkbox" class="edit-checkbox group" name="groups[]" value="4" >
```

---

Then here is a solution to your issue: [JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/njcw9Lav/4/)

```js
$('.group').on('change', function() {
    var totalSeen = $("input.group:checked").length;
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        $('#user').prop('checked', true);
        return;
    } else if (totalSeen == 0) {
     $('#user').prop('checked', false);
       return;
    } 
});
```

```css
.module {
  background: #fff;
  width:100%;
  height: 80px;
  display:block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.checkbox {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="module" id="1">
<form action="">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="edit-checkbox group" name="groups[]" value="4" >
      <span>Groep 8</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="edit-checkbox1 group" name="groups[]" value="4" >
      <span>Groep 7</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" class="edit-checkbox group" name="groups[]" value="4" >
      <span>Groep 6</span>
  </div>
</form>
<br><hr><br>
<form action="">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="edit-checkbox" name="groups[]" value="4" id="man">
      <span>Manager</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="edit-checkbox" name="groups[]" value="4" id="admin">
      <span>Administrator</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" class="edit-checkbox" name="groups[]" value="4" id="user">
      <span>Gebruiker</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" class="edit-checkbox" name="groups[]" value="4" id="userRead">
      <span>Gebruiker (alleen lezen)</span>
  </div>
</form>
</div>

<div class="module" id="2">
x
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*"If one of these checkboxes is checked another checkbox with the id (#user) should be checked as well."*

I have changed `id`s to `class`es, because it's a bad practice, to use same `id`s on the page. And here it is (if you need an explanation - just ask):

```js
$('input').on('change', function() {
  var currentClass = $(this).attr('class');
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $('.' + currentClass).prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $('.' + currentClass).prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="checkBox1" type="checkbox">
<input class="checkBox1" type="checkbox">
<input class="checkBox1" type="checkbox">
<input class="checkBox1" type="checkbox">
<input class="checkBox1" type="checkbox">
<input class="checkBox2" type="checkbox">
<input class="checkBox2" type="checkbox">
<input class="checkBox2" type="checkbox">
<input class="checkBox2" type="checkbox">
<input class="checkBox2" type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created four check boxes with same group as shown below,

```
<body>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="group1"/> 1
<input type="checkbox" name="group1"/> 2
<input type="checkbox" name="group1"/> 3
<input type="checkbox" name="group1"/> 4
</div>
</body>
```

and below is my js code that marks all the check boxes as checked/unchecked accordingly when you check/uncheck any of the check box

```
$("input[name='group1']").click(function(){
$("input[name='group1']").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: While this is a better solution to duplicating Id's, classes would still be a better solution. Thats what classes were designed for.